# jomsocial connect module in joomla 1.6 w/ jomsocial 2.2.3 seems to be missing

Tags: joomla, facebook

i'm trying to add a facebook connect button to pages other than jomsocial's frontpage and it seems that i should be using the module mod_jomsocialconnect, but it isn't in my ~/modules folder.

anyone know:

- if in newer versions of joomla and jomsocial if the module should be there but isn't or if it's been moved/renamed/fused with other code...
- how i might go about getting a working "login through facebook" button in my login module (through pre/post text etc.) or basically anywhere else preferably without buying something like JFBConnect

i have spent quite awhile on google and documentation on jomsocial, joomla, and facebook. any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed it? It would have came with your JomSocial archive. Make sure you unzip modules_unzip_first_2.2.4.zip and you will find mod_jomsocialconnect.zip inside.

Comment: installed correctly as far as i can tell.  since this seems to indicate i should have it but don't, i'll take a look at my zip file again.  thanks!